# If $a^2 + b^2 = N$ (N is positive integer) is it possible that either a, or b, or both are not integer?

Tags: number-theory, integers

If $a^2 + b^2 = N$ (N is positive integer), does that 100% mean that both $a$ and $b$ are integers?

What if we have $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = N$ or any other power degree than two? What the rule would be then?

Comment: like $\sqrt2^2+\sqrt2^2=4?$

Comment: @J. W. Tanner   actually this is the answer...

Comment: $(3/5)^2+(4/5)^2=1$.

Comment: No there are plenty of counterexamples just generate a few yourself: $a=1$ and $b=\sqrt(5)$; JW Tanner's comment...etc.etc.etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for $a^2+b^2=N\in\Bbb N$ with $a, b\not\in\Bbb Z$.

This can be proved with an example such as  $a=b=\sqrt2\;$  $  (\sqrt2^2+\sqrt2^2=4).$

It is also possible for $a^2+b^2=N\in\Bbb N$ with $a\in\Bbb Z$ and $b\not\in\Bbb Z$; e.g., $a=1, b=\sqrt3$.

Comment: It is possible for $a^k+b^k+c^k=N\in \Bbb N$ without $a,b, $ and $c$ all being integers; choose $N$ such that $N-2$ is not a $k^{th}$ power and then take $a=b=1$ and $c=\sqrt[k]{N-2}$